# Header not positioning correctly in IE

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Working on a header and currently using Flexbox to position the header and everything is positioned center correctly like I want when I test locally on my Mac but when others on my team are testing in IE or Windows based machines the header is no longer being positioned in the center. It becomes full width positioned either left or right and I'm really not sure what I am missing or doing incorrectly. Any help would be appreciated.

What it should look like
[image]

What it's doing on a Windows machine
[image]

html

```
<header class="mcc-header ember-view">
<div class="mcc-full mcc-div">
    <div class="mcc-header-content">
    <a href="/" class="mcc-header-logo">
        <span class="mcc-logo-title">MCC Semi</span>
    </a>

    <ul class="mcc-header-nav">
        <li class="mcc-header-nav-item">
            <a href="" class="mcc-header-nav-link guide">Company Profile</a>
        </li>
        <li class="mcc-header-nav-item">
            <a href="" class="mcc-header-nav-link guide">News</a>
        </li>
        <li class="mcc-header-nav-item">
            <a href="" class="mcc-header-nav-link guide">Contact Us</a>
        </li>
        <li class="mcc-header-nav-item">
            <a href="" class="mcc-header-nav-link guide">EN | CN</a>
        </li>
        <li class="mcc-header-nav-item">
            <a href="" class="mcc-header-nav-link guide"></a>
        </li>
        <li class="mcc-header-nav-item">
            <a href="" class="mcc-header-nav-link guide">Login</a>
        </li>
        <li class="mcc-header-nav-item">
            <a href="" class="mcc-header-nav-link guide">Sign Up</a>
        </li>
    </ul>

    </div>
</div>
<div class="mcc-full">
    <div id="main-menu" class="mcc-header-menu">
        <div class="mcc-full">
    <div class="mcc-header-legal">
        <ul class="mcc-header-legal-list">
            <li class="mcc-header-legal-item">
                <a href="" class="guide">Products</a>
            </li>
            <li class="mcc-header-legal-item">
                <a href="" class="guide">Catalog</a>
            </li>
            <li class="mcc-header-legal-item">
                <a href="" class="guide">Applications</a>
            </li>
            <li class="mcc-header-legal-item">
                <a href="" class="guide">Quality</a>
            </li>
            <li class="mcc-header-legal-item">
                <a href="" class="guide">Calendar</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
        <form class="mcchf" id="mcchf-h-search" action="" method="get" title="" role="search">
            <label class="mcchf">Search</label>
            <input class="mcchf" id="mcchf-h-st" type="text" name="q" placeholder="Search">
            <label class="mcchf">Submit search query</label>
            <input class="mcchf" id="mcchf-h-sb" type="submit" value="">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</header>
```

css

```
.mcc-header {
background-color: #fff;
display: block;
padding-bottom: 24px;
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
height: 90px;
top: 0;
left: 0;
padding-right: 50px;
padding-left: 50px;
z-index: 800
}

.mcc-header-content {
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
padding-top: 6px
}

.mcc-header-nav {
column-count: 2;
display: block;
width: 100%
}

@media screen and (min-width:760px) {
.mcc-header-content {
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding-bottom: 0
}

.mcc-header-nav {
    column-count: 3;
    width: auto
}
}

@media screen and (min-width:1020px) {
.mcc-header .mcc-header-content {
    align-items: flex-start;
    padding-top: 0
}

.mcc-header .mcc-header-nav {
    column-count: 1;
    width: auto
}
}

.mcc-header-nav-item {
display: block;
text-align: center;
width: 100%
}

@media screen and (min-width:1020px) {
.mcc-header .mcc-header-nav-item {
    display: inline;
    text-align: left;
    width: auto
}
}

.mcc-header-nav-link {
display: block;
margin-bottom: 0;
padding-bottom: 20px;
padding-top: 4px;
white-space: nowrap
}

@media screen and (min-width:760px) {
.mcc-header-nav-link {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 24px
}
}

.mcc-header-legal {
border-bottom: none;
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
justify-content: center
}

.mcc-header-legal-list {
display: block;
text-align: center;
}

@media screen and (min-width:760px) {
.mcc-header-legal {
    align-items: baseline;
    flex-direction: row;
    margin-top: 0
}

.mcc-header-legal-list {
    text-align: left
}
}

.mcc-header-legal-item {
display: inline-block;
padding-right: 24px;
padding-top: 24px;
text-align: left;
white-space: nowrap
}

.mcc-header-legal-item:last-of-type {
padding-right: 0
}

@media screen and (min-width:1020px) {
.mcc-header .mcc-header-legal-item {
    margin-left: 0 !important;
    padding-top: 8px
}
}

.mcc-header-logo {
display: block;
flex-shrink: 0;
padding-bottom: 0;
padding-top: 8px;
position: relative
}

.mcc-header-logo .mcc-logo-title {
height: 1px;
width: 1px;
position: absolute;
overflow: hidden;
top: -10px
}

#mcchf-h-search {
position: absolute;
top: 56px;
right: 5rem;
width: 250px;
height: 22px
}

#mcchf-h-search label.mcchf {
display: none
}

#mcchf-h-st {
position: absolute;
right: 30px;
width: 225px;
height: 22px;
padding-left: 5px;
cursor: text;
color: #111;
border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
border-top: none;
border-left: none;
border-right: none;
background: #fff;
-webkit-appearance: none;
border-radius: 0;
text-transform: none
}

#mcchf-h-sb {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
right: 0;
overflow: hidden;
width: 18px;
height: 18px;
cursor: pointer;
white-space: nowrap;
color: #000;
border: 0;
background: url('');
}

input {
display: block;
margin-bottom: .667em;
font-family: inherit;
font-size: 1rem;
line-height: 1.333em;
text-transform: uppercase;
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
-moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
background-repeat: repeat-x;
background-size: .09em .09em;
background-position: 0 90%
}
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. I tested your code in Chrome and IE11. They rendered the same layout.

Comment: Flexbox is partially supported in IE11, so its bound to have some problems: https://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox